# Multidimensional array - how to get specific values from array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, phpexcel

I have converted Excel data into Php array using toArray()..

actually my result is

[image]

My question how to get value from this Multidimensional array? and also how to i get header and value  from array in separately?

[image]

Comment: have you tryed with foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

you can access value, by following the path of the array. so in your case :
`$yourArrayName['Worksheet'][0][0]`, will return `SNo`

Answer (score 0):

Get one value:

```
print_r($your_array['Worksheet'][0]);
```

Get values with loop:

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key; // 'Worksheet'
    print_r $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract all the values of specific key then you should use for or foreach or while loop...

its something like

```
<?php 
$array = YOUR ARRAY;
$c=count($array);
for ( $i=0; $i < $c; $i++)
{ 
    echo $array[$i]['StudentName'];
 } 
?>
```

else if you want to get a specific value manually You can easily traverse to your value as

```
$array = YOUR ARRAY 
echo $ara['Worksheet'][0]['StudentName']
```